# Execution of event handlers in vertx

Tags: vert.x

If I have the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    vertx.eventBus().send("some-address", some-handler);
}
```

Are all the calls to the *some-handler* in this loop executed parallel or sequential? If sequential, what would be the right approach in order to get parallel execution?

Regards

Comment: Please check the syntax of send method. You are supposed to send some data as second parameter. Handler(replay handler) is the third optional parameter. And if you give will be executed sequentially but in random order as the replay comes from the other handler whose address you give as first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The execution is "sequential" since *sending* a message will result in only one "handler" registered — at the address receiving the message. Theoretically, if you want a parallel execution, you must deploy two (or more) verticles registered for that particular "handler" and start *publishing* messages. Keep in mind that Vert.x *does not* have concurrency for a single verticle, which is the main point of the platform anyway.

Additionally, have a look at this [link](http://joearms.github.io/2013/04/05/concurrent-and-parallel-programming.html). That's the best (and concise) explanation I've seen so far for **Concurrent and Parallel** programming; will definitely give you a clue of *what is what*, although the *jargon* varies from language to language.